# Div not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display only those divs that have a span class team that contains tname.

I have-

```
<div class="PERSON">
    <span class="name">Person_name</span>
    <span class="title">Person_title</span>
    <span class="team">Person_team</span>
</div>
```

I have the following code -

```
function dispTeam(tname)
{
   alert(tname);
   var e=document.getElementsByClassName("PERSON");
   for(var m=0;m<e.length;m++)
   {
      if(e[m].document.getElementsByClassName("team")[0].innerHTML.indexOf(tname)==-1)
      {
          e[m].style.display="none";
      }
      else
      {
         e[m].style.display="block";
      }
   }
}
```

The alert is getting displayed but the divs aren't showing up. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code??? And check that whether you are going inside `else` part or not??

Comment: Please put your `PERSON` class here

Comment: This would be really easy in jQuery, if you were open to using it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
e[m].document.getElementsByClassName(...
```

you have to do:

```
e[m].getElementsByClassName(...
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried that. It gives the same result as well. Divs aren't getting displayed. Only alert is triggered.

Comment: Here you have a more descriptive demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/aBJ7V/2/

Comment: here is the pg I created. It isn't working and I don't know why - https://c9.io/mathcrazy/chart/workspace/Untitled3.html

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link, it has preety good knowledge about how to get Elements by using ClassNames.

[GetElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

the length is not corret, you should use:

```
for(var m=0;m<e.childNodes.length;m++)
```